# Sort array within React-Native state

Tags: arrays, reactjs, sorting, react-native, setstate

I've been trying to sort my objects within an array (schoolClasses) by date without success.

I get all classes with Firebase, and, for each class, I fetch its subject name with Firebase.

Then I sort the array by date and call setState, passing the sorted array:

```
export default class SchoolClassesScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      schoolClasses: [],
      currentClass: {}
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    FirebaseDatabase.database().ref('schoolClasses').once('value').then(snapshot => {
      let schoolClasses = snapshot.val();
      Object.keys(schoolClasses).forEach(key => {
        let schoolClass = schoolClasses[key];
        FirebaseDatabase.database().ref('subject/' + schoolClass.subject).once('value').then(snapshot => {
          schoolClass.subject = snapshot.val().name;
          let schoolClasses = this.state.schoolClasses.slice();
          schoolClasses.push(schoolClass);
          schoolClasses.sort((sc1, sc2) => new Date(sc1.date) - new Date(sc2.date));
          this.setState({schoolClasses: schoolClasses, currentClass: schoolClasses[0]});
        });
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Sorting or not does not make any difference. The array is always in the same order.

What am I missing? Thanks.

UPDATE 1

Database structure:

```
{
  "schoolClasses" : {
    "schoolClass1" : {
      "date" : "2017-11-07 18:45:00",
      "subject" : "security"
    },
    "schoolClass3" : {
      "date" : "2017-11-09 18:45:00",
      "subject" : "database1"
    },
    "schoolClass2" : {
      "date" : "2017-11-08 18:45:00",
      "subject" : "database1"
    }
  },
  "subject" : {
    "security" : {
      "name" : "I.T. Security"
    },
    "database1" : {
      "name" : "Database I"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post example data of the array?

Comment: you need to set `schoolClasses = schoolClasses.sort(() => /* ...*/);`

Comment: Are you sure that the `date` property of the school class is parsable by `new Date()` such that it gives an accurate value that can be compared? Also, you are accessing `this.state.schoolClasses` while building up the array asynchronously. This can be problematic because you don't know if `this.state` has an up-to-date copy of the array. I would consider using the function callback style of `this.setState`.

Comment: David, I've updated my question. bennygenel, it does not fix the issue. A. Goodale, yes, it's parseable. Even with setState callback it does not work.

Comment: When I tried the code in fiddle with the same data provided.  It was working fine and the state gets updated properly

Comment: It works when I debug it. It does not work when I run it normally. I think it's something like a race condition ...